# Custom animation - AnimationHelper

Tags: ios, swift, animation

I have been trying to learn how to create a custom transition animation. I found an online guide at this link https://www.raywenderlich.com/110536/custom-uiviewcontroller-transitions.

However, there is this class that is used and gives an error:

```
AnimationHelper.perspectiveTransformForContainerView(containerView)
snapshot.layer.transform = AnimationHelper.yRotation(M_PI_2)
```

My code says AnimationHelper is an "unresolved identifier"...

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong? Or how do I implement AnimationHelper in my code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears that the `AnimationHelper` class is not defined in your project.

**Are you using the starter project that was provided in the tutorial?** You do not need to implement this class, it should be provided for you by the author of the tutorial.

From the tutorial page:

> Note: Don’t let AnimationHelper confuse you. It’s a small utility class, responsible for adding perspective and rotation transforms to your views. Feel free to have a look at the implementation.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```swift
struct AnimationHelper {
  static func yRotation(_ angle: Double) -> CATransform3D {
    return CATransform3DMakeRotation(CGFloat(angle), 0.0, 1.0, 0.0)
  }

  static func perspectiveTransform(for containerView: UIView) {
    var transform = CATransform3DIdentity
    transform.m34 = -0.002
    containerView.layer.sublayerTransform = transform
  }
}
```